# Is there any book where specific heat capacities are given?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, databases

I want to find the value of the specific heat capacity of aluminium nitrate nonahydrate, in order to calculate mixing effects in a chemical reaction. I am looking for a source, such as a book or link to an online PDF, which would be appreciated.

Comment: Does you reaction occur in water solution, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, the entire reaction is taking place in water at 60 deg C.

Comment: Then you don't really need what you ask about, and that for two reasons: because your specific compound does not exist in water solution, and because its heat capacity is negligible compared to that of water.

Answer (score 3):

There are several databases of thermochemical properties, a number of them being listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_databases_for_pure_substances#Enthalpy,_heat_content_and_heat_capacity) (at the bottom). Most of them are not freely available online, but require subscription. I've searched online but couldn't find that information freely available.

Another possible way to get the information would be through a search of the published literature (scientific papers). You can, for example, find this information on magnesium nitrate in a [1944 paper in *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01237a021). However, I had no such luck with Al(NO<sub>3</sub>)<sub>3</sub> · 9 H<sub>2</sub>O .

---

*Clarification: the answer above is for the crystalline compound aluminium nitrate nonahydrate, which as @Ivan stated, may not be what you actually *need* for your calculation if the reaction is in water.*

Comment: As a first step, there's also th Dulong-Petit approximation that *molar* heat capacity of solids is ≈ 3 R which should be OK at room temperature. Of course reality doesn't behave ideally, but it should be good for getting the order of magnitude.